# nest non pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have a problem to nest a non pure function.The function `f` has two arguments, `i` and `j`, it can come out four results `{i + 2, j - 1}`, `{i + 1, j}`, `{i, j + 1}`, `{i - 1, j + 2}` which I use If conditional to programme it. But now, what I want to do it's to nest this function, like I input `i = 1`, `j = 0`, then the four results will follow the F subsequently. it's like if I want nest it 3 times, then it should have 12 results. but the error show that "part specification [][]is longer than depth of the object".

**Update**

```
f = Function[{i, j}, 
     If[(i > 0) && (j > 0), 
      {{i + 2, j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i - 1, j + 2}}, 
      If[j == 0, 
       {{i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i - 1, j + 2}}, 
       {{i + 2, j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}}
      ]
     ]
    ];
```

This the function I use. I hope I can nest this function several times and get a long list results. The one step work for example put `i = 1`, `j = 1`, I get `{{3, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 3}}`.

Comment: If your function name is [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) then there might be a problem. It's best not to use capitals as they conflict with built-in functions.

Comment: actually, I used N' and it's results if fine. just can't be nest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Define your function:

```
f[i_, j_] := 
  If[i > 0 && 
    j > 0, {{i + 2, j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i - 1, j + 2}},
   If[j == 0,
    {{i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i - 1, j + 2}},
    {{i + 2, j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}}
    ]
   ];
```

Then

```
NestList[Flatten[f @@@ #, 1] &, {{1, 1}}, 3]

(* {{{1, 1}}, 
    {{3, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 3}}, 
    {{4, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, 
     {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {0, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {0, 4}}, 
    {{5, 0}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {5, 0}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, 
     {1, 4}, {5, 0}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {5, 0}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, 
     {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {0, 5}, {5, 0}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, 
     {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {0, 5}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, 
     {0, 5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {0, 5}, {2, 3}, 
     {1, 4}, {0, 5}}
   } *)
```

The tricky part is that, the depth of the expression increases with each iteration, making it hard to use `Map` or `Apply`. That's why `Flatten` is in there, and also why the initial expression `{{1, 1}}` has an extra level of `List`, `{...}` -- for consistency so you don't need to try to `Apply` `f` at a different level in each iteration.

I'm assuming it's okay that the results get `Flatten`ed since you made no mention of it in the question. There is, of course, structure being lost. But without `Flatten`ing, the expression you're left with after 3 iterations has [`Depth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Depth.html) 6 and not much to recommend using it.

Comment: you have solved the problem perfectly, I don't know why they won't suggest to say thanks in the comments. but whatever, I must thank you!

Comment: @IvyGao No problem at all! The best way to say thanks is to upvote any useful posts, and click on the tick to accept an answer if it solves your problem successfully.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a green hands and couldn't find the accept button. But, I suppose the system will handle it.

Comment: Sadly, no. The system won't "handle it". It's  It's a greyed out tick to the left of this answer, under the number and voting arrows. You can look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) or take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! :-)